# Mockito error as org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue on a unit case

Tags: java, mockito

I am trying to run this test case but I am getting

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
Amount$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$3216e5a5 cannot be returned by getAmount()
getAmount() should return Amount
***
```

```
Amount amount = mock(Amount.class);
doReturn(amount).when(entityTotal).getAmount(); // ABOVE ERROR ON THIS LINE
```

Full test case

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(EntityFileEnricher.class)
public class EntityFileEnricherTest {
    @InjectMocks
    private EntityFileEnricher fileEnricher;
    
    @Test
    public void getInfoWithCredit() throws Exception {
        fileEnricher = spy(fileEnricher);

        CollectionType collectionType = mock(CollectionType.class);
        doReturn(Arrays.asList(collectionType)).when(comsUtil).getPmtCollectionType(any(Order.class));

        PaymentMethodType paymentMethod = mock(PaymentMethodType.class);
        doReturn(paymentMethod).when(collectionType).getPaymentMethod();

        com.example.orders.types.v2.PaymentInstrument paymentIns = mock(com.example.orders.types.v2.PaymentInstrument.class);

        doReturn(paymentIns).when(paymentMethod).getPaymentInstrument();
        doReturn("buyer_ins_key").when(paymentInstrument).getPaymentInstrumentKey();

        EntityTotal entityTotal = mock(EntityTotal.class);
        doReturn(entityTotal).when(collectionType).getTotalAmount();

        Amount amount = mock(Amount.class);
        doReturn(amount).when(entityTotal).getAmount();   // ERROR HERE
        doReturn(1.0).when(amount).getValue();
        ....
```

Comment: is `entityTotal` a field of Amount?

Comment: @silentsudo `Amount` is a field of `entityTotal`.